# C# inherit value from a different .cs file

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to print the values from one .cs file, by calling that class in another .cs file.
Like so

### BaseClass.cs

```
namespace BaseClass
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public void ValueClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value 1");
        }
    }
}
```

### DerivedClass.cs

```
namespace DerivedClass
{
    public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public void MyValueClass()
        {
            this.ValueClass();
        }
    }
}
```

So when I run the files with "DerivedClass" as startup project, it should print "value 1" to the prompt.

However I get this error in DerivedClass.cs: The type or namespace name 'baseClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Can someone help me to solve this please?

I have been searching a lot for answers to this problem with inheritance, but all I can find are really long and overly complex versions of this example, which just induce additional problems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class `BaseClass` is actually `BaseClass.BaseClass` because of the following code:

```
namespace BaseClass
{
  ...
}
```

So when you use it in DerivedClass it should be :

**Either** :

```
using BaseClass; //use the namespace you defined BaseClass in

namespace DerivedClass
{
    public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public void MyValueClass()
        {
            this.ValueClass();
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
namespace DerivedClass
{
    //use the fully qualified name for BaseClass:
    public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass.BaseClass
    {
        public void MyValueClass()
        {
            this.ValueClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass.BaseClass` instead. What happen is you are using different Namespace and for your `DerivedClass` to be able to find it, you need to specify the full Assembly name, `Namespace`.`Class`.

Since namespace and class name are the same declaring `using namespace` might result to

> `BaseClass` is a `namespace` but is used like a 'type'

error (if located on the same .cs file).

Comment: Do you mean: namespace DerivedClass
{
    public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass.BaseClass
    {
        public void MyValueClass()
        {
            this.ValueClass();
        }
    }
}

Comment: As side (unrelated) tip to OP: you should avoid to name classes with namespace name...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `using BaseClass;` to your DerivedClass File. The problem is, that your `DerivedClass` doesnt know which `BaseClass` it has to inherit from (In case there are multiple). So you need to specify the `namespace`, in which the `BaseClass` lies.

Comment: In revition I got i working by making my files like so:

Comment: namespace InheritBaseclass
{
    public class BaseClass1
    {
        public static void PrintMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HEJSA");
        }
    }
}

Comment: using InheritBaseclass;

namespace MainInherit
{
    class Program: BaseClass1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintMethod();
        }
    }
}